# How to declare multiple servlets from one class definition using annotation

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, servlets

Using web.xml I can declare multiple servlets based on one Java class, like this:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>servlet1<servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.xx.servClass<servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>servlet2<servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.xx.servClass<servlet-class>
</servlet>
```

And then I can serve two urls using the two servlets so they can do some tasks based on their identities, such as `this.getServletName()`. How can I achieve the same thing using annotations? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think that it is possible to put 2 @WebServlet annotations on the same class, however you can accomplish your goal by mapping the servlet to 2 different URLs like this:

```
@WebServlet(name=”Servlet1”, urlPatterns={"/url1", "/url2"})
public class ServClass extends HttpServlet {
```

And then you can determine which URL was used by examining the request object.

For reference, see [the servlet 3.0 spec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27221145/how-to-declare-multiple-servlet-from-one-class-definition-using-annotation).